# RewriteRule to load images from another host?

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2

On our development server we have only the code and to save space they do not include the graphical content. I previously had some rewrite rules working to load all images from the live site based on the extension, but they've suddenly stopped working and I can't seem to get them working again.

If I wanted to grab all files ending in .gif, .jpg or .png and have them picked up from another hostname/ip address what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> If I wanted to grab all files ending in .gif, .jpg or .png and have them picked up from another hostname/ip address what is the best way to do this?

Something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(gif|png|jpe?g)$ http://other-host.com/$1.$2 [NC,L,R=301]
```

You can replace the `R=301` with `P` if you'd rather reverse proxy as opposed to redirecting.